# while creating customer account in magento 2 it shows "we can't save the customer"

Tags: magento2, customer, error, create, account

**1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Mageplaza\CustomerApproval\Model\Config\Source\AttributeOptions does not exist**

Comment: You are using a third party module and it is not core magento issue. It is better to open the issue on Magepalza page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by removing the "Customer Approval" extension.

Looking at [the source code of this extension](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-customer-approval/blob/master/Setup/UpgradeData.php#L95) it creates a customer entity attribute that implemented the mentioned class as a source model.

Check in database table `eav_attribute` for the attribute `is_approved`, and delete that row.

Comment: thanks sander mangel now it's working fine.